# bert-base-uncased tokenizer lost word in sentence

Tags: pytorch, tokenize

here is my code. I want to get the embedding of each word in the sentence. If the word was split to several subwords, I take embedding of the first subword. So the number of embedding should be the same as the length of the sentence. But the tokenizer lost some words.

```py
        tokenizer = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-based-uncased')

        ..........

        words = inst.ori_words # list type: represent a sentence split by words 
        orig_to_tok_index = []
        res = tokenizer.encode_plus(words, is_split_into_words=True)
        subword_idx2word_idx = res.word_ids(batch_index=0)
        prev_word_idx = -1
        for i, mapped_word_idx in enumerate(subword_idx2word_idx):
            """
            Note: by default, we use the first wordpiece/subword token to represent the word
            If you want to do something else (e.g., use last wordpiece to represent), modify them here.
            """
            if mapped_word_idx is None:## cls and sep token
                continue
            if mapped_word_idx != prev_word_idx: 
                ## because we take the first subword to represent the whold word
                orig_to_tok_index.append(i)
                prev_word_idx = mapped_word_idx
        print(words)
        print(subword_idx2word_idx)
        print(orig_to_tok_index)
        assert len(orig_to_tok_index) == len(words)
```

here is the special case

```
words: ['mossbauer', 'spectroscopy', 'has', 'been', 'used', 'to', 'study', 'the', 'R3(Fe,Ti)29', ',', '(', 'r', '\ue5fb', 'Nd', ',', 'Sm', ')', 'compounds', '.']
subword_idx2word_idx: [None, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, None]
orig_to_tok_index: [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

This code is used in a sequence labeling task, so I need to maintain the length of the sentence. And there is some **Unicode **char in my dataset.

In the output subword_idx2word_idx, I couldn't find wordidx 12. The tokenizer lost the word '\ue5fb' in the original sentence. How to fix such problem for example as the tokenizer to replace the unknown word with  automatically.

It works ok if I use `tokenizer = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')` . But now I was asked to used 'bert-based-uncased'.

I want by code can works noramlly, maybe I have the following ideas:

1. Will all non-ACSII char discarded by bert-uncased ? If so, can I replace them in preprocessing by another special token? what is this token? '[unk]' '[UNK]' or so on
2. Can I ask the tokenzier to do the above thing automatically.